# Send email automatically to Telegram Channel

Tags: email, send, telegram, channel

I found a Telegram Bot named "Telegram Email" that creates a personal email address. When I send email to that address I read the content of email in the bot.
I would like that all people in my private channel could see the content of email automatically.
"Telegram Email" bot is administrator in my private channel.
How can I do? Is it possible to send email directly to my channel? Is it possible to forward message written in "Telegram Email" bot automatically to my private channel?
Thanks for suggestions

Answer (score 2):

Use @wwpagerbot in Telegram. You can use /register@wwpagerbot command in your channel and get email for this channel

Answer (score 1):

You are using a bot not developed by you so if it has no features to post in channels you can't.

About the automatic forwards, you can but you should develop a userbot using mtproto API with your account that does it